# Combobox MouseWheel and ICommand CanExecute

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, mousewheel

I have some objects in a combobox and depending on the selecteditem I want to enable or disable some buttons using ICommand CanExecute. However, when I hover over the combobox and mouse wheel scroll to select a new item, the selecteditem changes but the CanExecute never fires until I click on a different control. Is there someway to fire CanExecute each time selecteditem changes?

Comment: I think I found the answer to my own question. I can call CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() from the MV and it causes all the ICommand::CanExecutes to fire. So I just put that in my SelectedItem set function.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work by setting UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"? It seems like it should work this way but it doesnt.